# ¿Cómo se dice "flyer" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Si vas por la calle de una gran ciudad, normalmente de noche, siempre encuentras a algún joven que te da unas cartulinas pequeñas con información de discotecas, bares, etc. donde pasar un rato. A veces, la tarjeta incluso contiene algún descuento o promoción.

A eso le llamamos con la palabra inglesa **"flyer"**.

Me pregunto: ¿existe alguna palabra castellano que lo traduzca?

Wikipedia menciona *"volante"* pero es algo que nunca oí en este contexto (suena a algo médico). También pensé en *"panfleto"*, pero el [DRAE me dice que](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=nWczYpACpDXX2uiZlXul) esto se refiere a *"Libelo difamatorio"* o *"Opúsculo de carácter agresivo"*.

Comment: Aparte de "planfleto" yo habría sugerido "folleto", pero ni "folleto", ni "tríptico", ni "tarjeta de propaganda"  me hacen pensar en los _flyers_ de discotecas, que tienen casi el tamaño de tarjetas de visita.

Comment: He oído «octavilla» alguna vez, pero en mi zona «flyer» es la típica palabra que te la entienden mejor en inglés que traducida.

Comment: What about `hoja de anuncio`? or `hoja de aviso`

Comment: Most of the Spanish language interpreters in Austin would agree with **volante**

Comment: Volante. Un panfleto lleva mas de una pagina y se dobla.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como ya he insinuado en el comentario a la pregunta, ninguna traducción me satisface. No porque me suenen mal, sino porque a veces para traducir hay que pensar en el efecto que producimos sobre el interlocutor. Si hablamos de *flyers* de discoteca, cualquier otra palabra que no sea esa va a generar más miradas raras que verdadera comunicación.

Dicho eso, he aquí la postura de la Fundéu, que básicamente se puede resumir en «depende»:

> [C]on toda propiedad se puede traducir con el español «volante», sin
>   que pierda nada de su esencia. En algunos países le llaman «suelto» a
>   esa página que antes en propaganda se conoció como «mariposa». En
>   algunos casos es más que un simple volante y se convierte en un
>   «folleto», que es la traducción para la voz del francés que se citó en
>   el segundo párrafo de esta sección. En algunos casos se puede utilizar
>   la palabra «prospecto» para expresar mejor el concepto. ([Fuente](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/de-palabra-en-palabra-suquet-3739/)).
>
> «[O]ctavilla» o «folleto», mejor que «flyer»  (o «panfleto» si tiene
>   sentido difamatorio). ([Fuente](https://twitter.com/fundeu/status/74449880743022592)).

Comment: `Brochure` también podría ser pertinente. Pero sí volante me parece lo más adaptado

Comment: @Joze *Brochure* es otra palabra inglesa, con eso no ganamos nada.

Comment: @Gorpik No, **Brochure** es una palabra francesa. Y es francesa porque fue allá que se hicieron los primeros brochures. Así que sí ganamos mucho dado que hablamos del origen.

Comment: @Joze De acuerdo, francesa. Pero cambiar una palabra inglesa por otra francesa sigue sin parecerme ninguna ganancia.

Answer (score 15):

En Argentina la traducción más general de *flyer* es, efectivamente, *volante*. El término se usa tanto para propaganda política como comercial.

Pero en general, un volante es de papel, no de cartulina. Los materiales que describes invitando a discotecas se llaman simplemente *tarjetas*, y quienes las reparten *tarjeteros*.

Comment: También **folletos** , aunque es menos común para el caso que describe el OP.

Comment: Volante también en Chile (y también en distintos tipos de papel). Aunque flyer se usa más, y son intercambiables

Answer (score 5):

En Colombia la traduccion exacta es **volante**, que define a un elemento promocional impreso que se reparte en la calle o se inserta en revistas y periodicos.

Answer (score 5):

¿Qué tal [**pasquín**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S5LeDet)?

> 3. m. Hoja de papel con publicidad, propaganda u otro mensaje.

Comment: Genial primera contribución. Bienvenido a Spanish.se!

Answer (score 3):

En México se utiliza la palabra ***volante*** para propaganda repartida en trozos o en una hoja entera tamaño carta de papel, por las calles o en postes de utilidades.  Por lo general lleva información solamente de un lado de la hoja. Si es de buena calidad y contiene bastante información puede llegar a ser llamado ***folleto***. Es un ***tríptico*** si es del tipo de folletos doblado en tres partes iguales.

Aún así mismo, se le podría llamar a cualquiera de estos un ***volante***.

Answer (score 2):

En Inglés se suele usar una única palabra para definir distintas cosas, algo que en el castellano o español se estructura y se piensa de manera diferente. Por tal motivo, por ejemplo en Argentina, para traducir flyer al español, se debe contemplar su entorno, y de acuerdo a esto puede ser "volante", "tarjeta", "afiche", "ficha" u otra acepción. Para una disco un flyer sería una tarjeta, para una publicidad en mano puede ser un volante, para una publicidad fija sería un afiche, para un mensaje adjunto con datos sería una ficha y así muchos etcéteras!

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen más arriba, en Argentina les llamamos "volantes" y si son chiquitos les decimos "volantitos" o directamente "papelitos"... "Tarjeta" y "tarjetita" también están bien. Además "volante" deriva de "volar" tanto como *flyer* de *fly*... Es la mejor traducción.

Ejemplo de uso:

> Ya me dieron el volante para la disco nueva.

Answer (score 0):

**volante**

Ejemplos de su uso:

> El *flyer* o *volante* es un medio publicitario económico y muy eficiente si tienes las herramientas de cómo utilizarlo y medirlo, puede ser de gran utilidad para promover nuestros productos y servicios. http://www.codigopostalmx.com/articulos/caracteristicas-flyer-publicitario.html
>
> Cómo poner 4 volantes en una página https://techlandia.com/poner-4-volantes-pagina-como_248596/

Creo que el solo hecho de imprimirse en papel más grueso no cambia esta selección de término.

Nota: la diferencia entre *volante* y *folleto* en la en la práctica es que el folleto consiste de más de una hoja y el volante consiste de una hoja tamaño carta o una hoja más pequeña.  (Si la hoja es más grande que tamaño carta, entonces ya no es volante.)

Answer (score -1):

Yo habría dicho simplemente propaganda, que es el término general para la publicidad y que no genera ningún tipo de malinterpretación.

Answer (score -1):

**Volante**. Un panfleto lleva más de una página y se dobla.

He aquí la etimologia de [volante](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=volante) y la de [panfleto](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=panfleto) donde se denomina folleto difamatorio, propaganda política. Ninguna definición centra el nombre a una hoja de papel. La hoja de cartulina es también una hoja.